# Somehow this if statement isn't working?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm developing with new android 4.0 SDK on Eclipse.

Somehow this simple if statement is not working.
I get data from another activity through a bundle:

```
Bundle gotBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
gotPack = gotBundle.getString("key");
Toast.makeText(this, gotPack, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i've tried outputting 'gotPack' on a toast and alert dialogue box, both of which return a string value 'Pattern 1'. (which is what i wanted so far)

Now when i try my if statement:

```
  if (gotPack == "Pattern 1") {
     filePath="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.p2;   
     Toast.makeText(this, "WORKED1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

it refuses to enter into the if statement, i have tested this as it does not produce the toast output or any other results. What can i be doing wrong? gotPack is initially identified as a string.

Comment: Try using the equals() method rather than "==", and also use a trim on your gotPack variable. Also, trying the debugger would greatly help.

Comment: Well, I think this guy got his answer.

Comment: @android_man1 see my answer for an explanation of why you should use `.compareTo(...) == 0` over `.equals(...)`.

Comment: your method also works, for my needs either would be suitable as the string will never change

Comment: If you have a finite set of strings, perhaps an `ENUM` is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String comparison you need to use `.equals()`

`if ("Pattern 1".equals(gotPack)) {`

Java Objects are typically started with a capitol letter (*O*bject, *S*tring, *L*ist, *I*nteger) while primatives are lowercase (*i*nt, *d*ouble). Any object must override the .equals() method in order to do a proper comparison of the objects otherwise you're comparing the memory reference and not the object itself.

Answer (score 3):

Using `==` with an object in Java compares the references, to check that they refer to the exact same object. You want to use `.equals()` instead, like so:

```
"Pattern 1".equals(gotPack)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare Strings using `==`

```
if (gotPack.equals("Pattern 1")) {
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

In Java you should use `equals` to compare String like this:

```
"Pattern 1".equals(gotPack)
```

this should resolve your issue

When you use == it will work if both the `String` refer to the same object

```
String str1 = "test";
String str2 = "test";
```

in this case `str1 == str2` will be true

but if this would have been like this :

```
String str1 = "test";
String str2 = new String("test");
```

in this case `str1 == str2` will be false, but `str1.equals(str2)` will be true as equals does the comparison on the value and not on the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `==` operator works is that it looks at both elements and see if they're located at the same memory address. This means that if two equal strings are located at different memory locations, `==` won't recognize it.

Instead, you should use the `equals()` method.

```
if (gotPack.equals("Pattern 1")) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (gotPack.equals("Pattern 1")) {
 filePath="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.p2;   
 Toast.makeText(this, "WORKED1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

[String comparison with Android, look for equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)